# Is it correct to say "I am ready already"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Say I am meeting with a friend after some stuff is done, and want to tell him when I will arrive at his place, so he can leave home on time.

Is it correct to write something like this to him?

> I am **ready already**

To me it sounds etymologically a bit odd, and also the sound is repetitive. However, does it sound good to English native speakers?

Comment: What do you mean by ***etymologically** a bit odd?* I've no doubt the two components of, say, ***flip-flops*** (minimalist sandals) are etymologically related, but does that make the usage "odd"?

Comment: We don't use the adverb _well_ as the complement with a linking verb like _sound_. _Sound_ (and _smell, look, taste, feel_, etc.) take an adjective: _"That sounds **good**."_ "Good" is a subject complement: it modifies _that_, not the verb.

Comment: In many American dialects, _already_ is an interjection expressing impatience. "I'm _ready_, already!" might be heard from someone who is being pestered to prepare for something, but who has been prepared for an hour and is tired of being pestered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct and makes logical sense. But it sounds odd because of the use of two similar-sounding words in a row. We generally avoid using words that sound similar in the same sentence because it can be confusing, especially if you are hearing it rather than reading it. Unless you are deliberately engaging in word play, like a poem, song, or rhetorical statement or phrase.

A person might well say this without really thinking about it. If I was writing, I'd probably use a different word for one or the other, like "I am prepared already" or "I am ready now".

Comment: Or you could say it deliberately, for fun.   Word repetition can be clever or funny in the right context.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, that's what I was trying to say in my comment about word play. "lovey-dovey", "sky high", "fat cat", etc.